Outlook Cloud signature adding 1px padding to CSS/HTML table
I have an HTML/CSS file using nested tables to be used as an email signature in Outlook cloud, and while the code seems to work as intended in VS Code preview or CodePen, when pasting it into Outlook, a 1px padding or margin is added around every table and nested table, ignoring the CSS resets.
How it should look (and how it looks in VS Code/Codepen):

How it looks after pasting it in Outlook (Cloud) > Settings > Compose and Reply> Email signature:


I've tried tinkering with dozens of different properties and cannot make it work. Any idea of what property might be causing this?
Findings:

It seems that Outlook ignores the property border-spacing, which might be fixed to 1 px (changing it to 0 or a big size with border-collapse: separate does nothing when pasting).

You can see the Codepen here:
HTML:
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table id="nested-table-left">
                <tr id="row-1-left">
                    <td>left nested table row 1 </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="row-2-left">
                    <td>left nested table row 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="row-3-left">
                    <td>
                        <table id="nested-nested-table">
                            <tr id="nested-nested-table-row-1 ">
                                <td id="nested-nested-table-row-1">nested nested table row 1</td>
                                <td class="icon-cell"><img
                                        src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/012/659/360/original/geometric-square-logo-flat-simple-logo-free-vector.jpg">
                                </td>
                                <td class="icon-cell"><img
                                        src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/012/659/360/original/geometric-square-logo-flat-simple-logo-free-vector.jpg">
                                </td>
                                <td class="icon-cell"><img
                                        src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/012/659/360/original/geometric-square-logo-flat-simple-logo-free-vector.jpg">
                                </td>
                                <td class="icon-cell"><img
                                        src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/012/659/360/original/geometric-square-logo-flat-simple-logo-free-vector.jpg">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table id="nested-table-right">
                <tr>
                    <td>right nested table row 1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>right nested table row 2</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

CSS:
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

table {

    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: none;
    border-spacing: 0;
    background-color: blue;
}

td {
    vertical-align: top;
}

#nested-table-left {
    min-width: 368px;
    background-color: orangered;
}

#nested-table-right {
    min-width: 180px;
    background-color: pink;
}

#nested-nested-table {
    min-width: 180px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

#row-1-left>td {
    height: 100px;
}

#row-2-left>td {
    height: 175px;
}

#nested-nested-table-row-1>td {
    height: 45px;
}

#nested-nested-table-row-1 {
    min-width: 168px;
}

.icon-cell {
    min-width: 50px;
}

img {
    display: block;
    min-width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    /* vertical-align: bottom; */

}

.icon-cell>img {
    float: right;
}


Try adding !important to the margin and/or padding.

I have tried (and also with other properties, like border-spacing: 0 !important, but it does not work.

Try this
add this lines in css for table
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: none;
    border-spacing: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    mso-table-lspace: 0pt; // this
    mso-table-rspace: 0pt; // this
}

Use inline style for table element
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
    ...
</table>

Or you can add empty  to fix this
<td style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
    <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACw=" width="1" height="1" style="display: block;">
</td>

